# How to Hash content to write in file as format mentioned as below?

Tags: ruby, string, file

> I have wrote my ruby script for that. In that you can check "all_data" has all required content.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'docx'

file_data = []
name_file = "test"
t = ""
array_desc = []
heading_hash = {}
all_data = {}
temp = ""
output = ""
folder_name = ""
directory_name = ""

flag = true
count = 0
md_file_name = ''
Dir.glob("**/*.docx") do |file_name|
 doc = Docx::Document.open(file_name)

 first_table = doc.tables[0]

 doc.tables.each do |table|
  table.rows.each do |row| # Row-based iteration
  row.cells.each_with_index do |cell, i|
    if i == 2 
      file_data << cell.text.gsub('=','')
    end
  end
 end
end

file_data.each_with_index do |l, d|
 if l.include? file_data[d]

 if ((l.strip)[0].to_i != 0)
   md_file_name = file_data[d].split(".")
    #start folder name
    if flag
      directory_name =  md_file_name[0].to_i
      flag =  false
    end
    count +=1

    t = file_data[d+1]

    if(array_desc.size > 0)
      heading_hash[temp] = array_desc
      all_data[md_file_name[0].strip] = heading_hash
      array_desc = []
    end 
  else
    if(t != l)
      array_desc << l
      temp = t
     end
    end
   end
  end

 if(array_desc.size> 0)
  heading_hash[temp] = array_desc
  all_data[md_file_name[0].strip] = heading_hash
  array_desc = []
 end

 all_data.each do |k, v|
  v.each do |(hk, hv)|
   if hk != ""
    chapter_no = k
    if (k[0,1] == 0.to_s)
      chapter_no = k
    else
      chapter_no = "0#{k}"
    end

    Dir.mkdir("#{chapter_no}") unless File.exists?("#{chapter_no}")
    output_name = "#{chapter_no}/#{File.basename("01", '.*')}.md"
    output = File.open(output_name, 'w')

    # output << "#"+"#{hk}\n\n"
    # output << "#{hv} \n\n"

    hv.each do |des|
      # puts des
    end
   end    
  end
 end
end
```

> > [source docx file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Zbmf0qFSzdNENSeXBxbGtTdkE/view?usp=sharing)
> >
> > download above file and put sctip and docx (source file) in same folder. When you will run script form terminal ($./script.rb) you will see folder name as 01,02.....etc. And inside there will be file with md extension.

## I want to output as below description:

```
    ## FOLDER 01 > FILE 01.md, here data in file like hk as heading (for Heading you can put # before hk)and hv
    ## FOLDER 02 > FILE 01.md, here data in file like hk as heading (for Heading you can put # before hk)and hv
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

> > Please use my code and check that is working or not.

```
Dir.glob("**/*.docx") do |file_name|
 doc = Docx::Document.open(file_name)

 first_table = doc.tables[0]

 doc.tables.each do |table|
  table.rows.each do |row| 
   row.cells.each_with_index do |cell, i|
    if i == 2
      file_data << cell.text.gsub('=','')
    end
   end
  end
 end
file_data.each_with_index do |l, d|
 if ((l.strip)[0].to_i != 0)
  md_file_name = file_data[d].split(".")

 #start folder name
 if flag
  directory_name =  md_file_name[0].to_i
  flag =  false
 end
 count +=1
 t = file_data[d+1]
 if(array_desc.size > 0)
    heading_hash[temp] = array_desc
    array_desc=[]
    all_data[file_data[d+1]] = array_desc
  end 
 else
  if(t != l)
    array_desc << l
    temp = t
  end
 end
end

chapter_no = 1
all_data.each do |k, v|
  Dir.mkdir("#{chapter_no}") unless File.exists?("#{chapter_no}")
  output_name = "#{chapter_no}/#{File.basename("01", '.*')}.md"
  output = File.open(output_name, 'a')

  output << "#"+"#{k}\n\n"

  v.each do |d|
   output << "#{d} \n"
  end
  chapter_no= chapter_no+1
 end
end
```

> > It will give exact output as you shared above. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Wow It is working as expected. Thank you so much @umishra . I have tested with file above.

Comment: Hey @UdayKumar Happy to here.